# Jquery-ui autocomplete with DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select, input

Please suggest good tutorial to feed jquery ui qutomplete with php and mysql or help me to fix the problem of my code. Tried all methods. Can't find wrong piece of code.

My php code looks like that

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['term']))
{
    $term = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

    $result = $db->query("SELECT company as value,id FROM main WHERE company LIKE '$term'") or die(mysqli_error());;
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) $results[] = array( 'id' => $row[0] , 'label' => $row[1], 'value' => $row[1] );
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Js code below

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "index.php",
    minLength: 2,//search after two characters
    select: function(event,ui){
    }
});
```

And HTML markup

```
<input id="auto" name="company"/>
```

What's wrong with the code? It doesn't generate autocomplete option.. No error in php log file. How to fix that problem?

Comment: There is a big security bug: A bad guy could send a $term like `"'; DROP DATABASE ..."` (SQL Injection)

Comment: what is your json response , can you add it

Comment: did you read my question at all? don't you see php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source param must be of type string, array or callback, and "[Defines the data to use](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source)", not the page used to get them. You should use something like (see [here for an example](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/)):

```
    $("yourSelector").autocomplete({  
        source: function(req, add){  
            $.get("index.php?...", function(data) {  
                var returnData= [];  
                $.each(data, function(i, val){  
                  returnData.push(val.property);  
                });  
                add(returnData);  
            });  
        }, [...]
```

Comment: My js is not good enough. please edit my code, thx in advance